# Почему диск C заполнился на 1.5 ГБ после следующего включения?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-7

Чистил я на днях системный диск ноутбука. Профессионально этим не занимаюсь, поэтому без каких-то сторонних программ обошелся, кроме антивируса.

Перенес переменные среды `TEMP` и `TMP`, папки с рабочего стола на `D`. Провел дефрагментацию диска, очистку диска не от системных файлов стандартными средствами `Windows`, поместил в карантин 12 вирусов. Удалил `.dmp` и не системные `.log` файлы. Удалось освободить 3.3 ГБ на диске.

Решил проверить быстродействие компьютера - перезапустил. Он стал загружаться быстрее, но вместо 3.3 ГБ свободного места система показала 1.5 ГБ. Очистил и системные файлы. Свободными стали 1,75 ГБ. Диск опять красный. Я понимаю, что место на диске должно постепенно заполняться, но не на 1.8 ГБ после первого же включения.

Из подозрительных программ есть только Yandex браузер от которого в загрузках было 6 установщиков. В чем может быть причина такого быстрого заполнения диска?

Comment: Своп подрос, вероятно

Comment: запусти любую утилиту для анализа использования диска, которая картинками покажет, в какой папке сколько места. Потом можно будет что-то думать. https://www.lifewire.com/free-disk-space-analyzer-tools-3986870

Comment: @Эникейщик Сегодня опять поеду к ноуту, посмотрю, отпишусь.

Comment: Размер свопа посмотрите. А вообще обновления очень много места занимают, они все на диске хранятся.

Comment: _очистку диска не от системных файлов стандартными средствами Windows_ скорей всего почистили файлы обновлений винды. После перезагрузки виндовс снова их накачала

Comment: Как минимум, разберитесь какие файл менялись/добавлялись с перезагрузки и какие/сколько они занимают места. Без этого говорить о чем-то - как гадать на кофейной гуще. P.S. Могу порекомендовать Scanner by Stefen Gerlach для проведения оценки занятого места.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, во всем был виноват Файл подкачки, как подсказали в комментариях. До 1,8 ГБ разросся. Оставил на С необходимые 200 мб файла подкачки и создал 2ГБ файл подкачки на D. Еще Система настроила обновления.

Comment: Нет никакого смысла оставлять 200 Мб файла подкачки на диске С. Раз перенесли его на диск D, то отключите его на диске С полностью.

Comment: @insolor Ок, понял. Уберу.